# Solve for b and d

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations, problem-solving

Solve for b and d in the following equation.

> A triangle with sides $(a, a, b)$ has the same area and the same perimeter as a triangle with sides $(c, c, d)$ where $a, b, c$ and $d$ are positive integers and with

$$ \frac{b^2+bd+d^2}{b+d} = 7^6   $$

I have tried several basic solutions like completing and other various solutions.

Source is [here](http://ssma.publishpath.com/Websites/ssma/images/Problems%20Section/March_2013.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A start:  If I see a quadratic and don't have a better idea, I feed it to the quadratic equation.  In this case, we have $$b^2+bd+d^2=7^6(b+d)\\b^2+b(d-7^6)+d^2-7^6d=0$$  for which [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2Bx%28y-7%5E6%29%2By%5E2-7%5E6y%3D0) reports $39$ integer solutions.  It only showed $5$ to start, and clicking on More Solutions didn't help.  Clicking on the copiable plantext got a Mathematica output that had them all.  They are $$b=-37758\quad d=64666\\ b=-37758\quad d=90741\\ b=-36015\quad d=57624\\ b=-36015\quad d=96040\\ b=-33614\quad d=50421\\ b=-33614\quad d=100842\\ b=-30576\quad d=43120\\ b=-30576\quad d=105105\\ b=-11951\quad d=13320\\ b=-11951\quad d=116280\\ b=-6174\quad d=6517\\ b=-6174\quad d=117306\\ b=0\quad d=0\\ b=0\quad d=117649\\ b=6517\quad d=-6174\\ b=6517\quad d=117306\\ b=13320\quad d=-11951\\ b=13320\quad d=116280\\ b=43120\quad d=-30576\\ b=43120\quad d=105105\\ b=50421\quad d=-33614\\ b=50421\quad d=100842\\ b=57624\quad d=-36015\\ b=57624\quad d=96040\\ b=64666\quad d=-37758\\ b=64666\quad d=90741\\ b=90741\quad d=-37758\\ b=90741\quad d=64666\\ b=96040\quad d=-36015\\ b=96040\quad d=57624\\ b=100842\quad d=-33614\\ b=100842\quad d=50421\\ b=105105\quad d=-30576\\ b=105105\quad d=43120\\ b=116280\quad d=-11951\\ b=116280\quad d=13320\\ b=117306\quad d=-6174\\ b=117306\quad d=6517\\ b=117649\quad d=0$$  Now you have to see if you can find $a$ and $c$ that will work from the geometry of isosceles triangles.

Comment: You can easily eliminate all the ones where $b \le 0$ or $d \le 0$. There are only like $12$ or so left after that.

Comment: @JimmyK4542:  I agree.  That would be my next step, followed by trying to find an appropriate $a,c$.  I suspect (but have not verified) that there are some nice quadratic equations to be solved to find that.  I think the original problem was to be solved without a computer, so you needed to do something smart involving factors of $7^6 \pm k$ That is why I called it a start.